# Jenkins shared libraries - import external class (without grab)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, import

In my library I have a class that need to import external class (io.fabric8 kubernetes client in my case..)

I wrote the import part without the classic groovy @Grab

```
package com.dor.libs

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.*
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient
```

In a strange way it works without Grab. I also delete my ~/.m2/repository/io/fabric8 and ~/.groovy/grapes

How its work? 
What is the dependency version?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: means this class in your classpath. for example in jenkins lib folder

Comment: Make sense. Thanks @daggett !